# Optimize search with ID's in jQuery (children selector?)

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a sort of grid from divs, and I'm doing this dynamically. For now I have few rows (every row with ID) and every element inside the row also has an ID (and it repeats, and I want  ID's to be unique as they should be).Basically, what I want to do is to tile the space with certain pictures and I want to add a unique ID to every certain element, so I could change it by click or even re-assign the value (change a tile, etc).

But I'm not pretty sure how I can do it, because in my loop I can only create one line (row) and then append it (by cloning). If anyone can suggest another way of looping and assigning certain ID, I will really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance!

My code is below.

```
minecraft.createDirt = function () {
  var columns = 20;
  var $row = $("<div/>", {
      class: 'row'
  });
  var $square = $("<div/>", {
      class: 'dirt cell'
  });

  $(document).ready(function () {
      //add columns to the the temp row object
      for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        var dr = $square.clone();
        dr.attr('id', 'dr'+i);
          $row.append(dr);
      }
      //clone the temp row object with the columns to the wrapper
      for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        var row = $row.clone();
        row.attr('id', 'rowdirt'+i);
          $("#wrapper").append(row);
      }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should iterate each cell and set `id` while appending it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //clone the temp row object with the columns to the wrapper
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        var row = $row.clone();
        var rowId = 'rowdirt' + i;
        row.attr('id', rowId);

        //add columns to the the temp row object
        for (var j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
            var dr = $square.clone();
            dr.attr('id', rowId + '_dr' + j);
            row.append(dr);
        }

        $("#wrapper").append(row);
    }
})
```

Comment: Oh, thank you so much! I tried to do something similar, but didn't succeed. Thanks again!

Comment: @AliceJarmusch, Glad I could help